# Why does my form get replaced with echo "0"?

Tags: php, html, forms

I got an error on my page that I can't identify, and when I view the site online it replaces all my site content with the value "0".
How come I can't see the forms, and is it communicating with the SQL server properly?

PS: Login works and session is created, so the connect.php does work properly.

Here is the code for members.php:

```
<?php 
// starting session
session_start();

// check if user is logged in
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    header('Location: http://wwww.gjertgjersund.com/');
    exit();
}
else
{
    // database connection
    require ('connect.php');

    //post record count
    $post_count = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts");
    $post_count_result = mysql_num_rows($post_count);

    //comment count
    $comment_count = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments");
    $comment_count_result = mysql_num_rows($comment_count);

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $newcategory = $_POST['newcategory'];
        if(!empty($newcategory))
        {
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT * INTO categories (category) VALUES ('$newcategory')";
            if($query)
        {
            echo 'New category added';
        }
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Error';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Missing newcategory';
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title> Folder </title>
<body>

<div class="wrap">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Create New Post</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Delete Post</a></li>
            <li><a href='logout.php'>Log Out</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Blog Home Page</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="maincontent">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Total Blog Post</td>
                <td><?php echo $post_count_result ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Total Comments</td>
                <td><?php echo $comment_count_result ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="categoryform">
            <form action="members.php" method="post">
                <label for="category">Add New Category</label>
                <input type="text" name="newcategory"/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should use `count(*)` instead of `*`.

Comment: on the insert * into?

Comment: Nope, for your counters `SELECT count(*) FROM posts` (and then not using `mysql_num_rows`.

Comment: the counters work. It was when I added the second form and the relating PHP that everything disappeared.

Comment: Anyway, [**please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I know your counter "works". I added this as a comment, not an answer. Just wanted to optimised your work.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course, thank you :) Is there a big difference in PDO and mysql_ functions?

Comment: @FriedBitz Yes, VERY big. PDO/MySQLi supports [parameterized/prepared statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), which would allow you to treat data as data, not part of SQL statement, hence greately decrease the dangor of SQL injection.

Comment: Ah, fair enough, I have tried rewriting it in PDO but I came across another problem, would you like to help me out in chat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT * INTO categories (category) VALUES ('$newcategory')";
```

should be

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO categories (category) VALUES ('$newcategory')";
```